# jQuery: раскрывающийся текст

Tags: jquery

Есть такая форма
[image]
при клике на верхний пункт - выезд курьера за оплатой - под ним должно появлять поле ввода адреса.
Поле появляется, но не получается сделать так, чтобы при клике на этот пункт он оказывался выбран - кружок в radio ставится при клике только на самом кружке, хотя всё взято в тег `<label>`, а если сначала выбрать какой-то другой пункт. а потом попробовать выбрать первый, он не выбирается вообще, куда не кликай.
http://jsfiddle.net/jgNHc/3/
И еще вопрос, как в скрипт добавить, чтобы если сначала выбрать первый пункт, а потом выбрать другой, чтобы поле адреса в таком случае свернулось?

Comment: я использую для подобных форм использую [knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/index.html), а вот и чистое [решение](http://jsfiddle.net/9m3Qh/1/)

Comment: со slideDown и slideUp получается красивее. какие-то очень странные штуки в этой knockout.js библиотеке))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучше всего будет навесить на поле с именем `courier_payment` обработчик события изменения (onchange):

http://jsfiddle.net/jgNHc/6/

```
$('input[name="courier_payment"]').change(function(){

  if(this.value == 'courier_payment') {
   $(".adress").slideDown('normal'); 
  }
  else {
    $(".adress").slideUp('normal'); 
  }
});
```

И да, давайте правильную форму. У вас все значения `value` были одинаковыми.

Теперь давайте проанализируем ваш код:

```
$(".click").click(function(){
   $(".adress").slideToggle('normal');
   return false;
});
```

При клике на элемент с классом `click` функция возвращает `false`. По этому и не происходит выбор пункта.

Comment: Да, понятно, спасибо. 
За подсказку на счет value спасибо, как-то пропустилось.
В моем коде без return false; поле ввода адреса появлялось и сразу сворачивалось.

Comment: @lampa объясните, пожалуйста, как так получается, что при повторном клике на первый пункт, под которым должен разворачиваться блок .adress, блок все равно остается развернутым, а сворачивается только при клике на другие пункты? а то я не совсем понимаю, как работает этот скрипт.

Comment: @Heidel всё просто. Если мы изменяем значение радио-кнопки courier_payment, то происходит событие, в котором происходит проверка значения радио-кнопки. Если оно соответствует courier_payment, то опускаем слайдер, если нет - поднимаем.